# Anyone know of a class that implements ISelectionService and/or IComponentChangeService

Tags: c#, .net, designer

In creating my own custom `ParentControlDesigner`, my `public override void Initialize( IComponent component )` processes these interfaces for working with the designer window

```
  ISelectionService service = (ISelectionService)this.GetService( typeof( ISelectionService ) );
  if ( service != null )
    service.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler( this.OnSelectionChanged );

  IComponentChangeService service2 = (IComponentChangeService)this.GetService( typeof( IComponentChangeService ) );
  if ( service2 != null )
    service2.ComponentChanged += new ComponentChangedEventHandler( this.OnComponentChanged );
```

I was wondering if someone knew any classes that implemented the `ISelectionService` and `IComponentChangeService`.  I want to see how they are built and possibly referenced.  In googling `ISelectionService`, I got a number of linked to either a definition or the `Initialization` implementation but no links to a class that actually implements `ISelectionService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two good articles on how to host the Visual Studio forms designer in your own application. These may give you the information you need.

- [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)
- [On DivElements](http://www.divil.co.uk/net/articles/designers/hosting.asp)